# How to go about creating a changelog.md on every merge from master to staging branch?

Tags: git, documentation, semantic-versioning, changelog

I would like to automatically create a `Changelog.md` every time I merge from `master` to `staging` or from `staging` to `production`. How to best go around doing this ?

Where I'm getting stuck is that the project I'm currently working on - built with `react-native` - I haven't set neither `git tags` nor `semver` just yet.  Do I need to have these things already set up before having a `Changelog.md` ? I think I might be over complicating things.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a GitHub app '[Changelogg.io](https://www.changelogg.io)' to automate changelog from merged pull requests.

It detects changes mentioned in the PRs and creates a release draft for it. After adding the release version, it automatically updates CHANGELOG.md and also has a web UI with filters for the generated changelog.

So, in this case, a changelog will be created on every merge to a branch. The changelog can be generated and maintained separately for each branch(master, staging, production) and can be rolled over too if needed.

[Youtube Walkthrough](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=17&v=nm2rghSMW1o&feature=emb_title)